# Changing the margin of a child element on parent scroll makes child flicker in IE9

Tags: jquery, css

I have an element that I want to stick to the top of its parent container. The parent container is scrollable and the siblings of the sticky element should scroll.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="fixed">
        <p>
            I shouldn't scroll, you know
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="scrollable">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9</li>
            <li>10</li>
            <li>11</li>
            <li>12</li>
            <li>13</li>
            <li>14</li>
            <li>15</li>
            <li>16</li>
            <li>17</li>
            <li>18</li>
            <li>19</li>
            <li>20</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.parent
{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin:20px 0;
    max-height:300px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
}

.fixed, .scrollable
{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.fixed
{
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    width:20rem;
}

.scrollable
{
    padding:10px;
}
```

The sticky element stays in place when you scroll the parent but it flickers in IE9. This is my jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.parent').scroll(function(e){
        $(this).find('.fixed').css('margin-top', $(this).scrollTop());
    });
});
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75kGT/). How can I remove the flickering in IE9? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use animate method instead of css method:

```
$(this).find('.fixed').animate({'margin-top': $(this).scrollTop()},1);
```

But it can be done just with css like this:

```
.fixed{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 350px;
height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, @C-link it actually still flickers in IE9 and also makes chrome and firefox flicker too.

Comment: It should just stick to the top of the parent container, which is scrollable, and not the whole document

Comment: Then you could use position: sticky; but it's not yet implemented.